# In Star Trek Discovery why are they able to beam out Admiral Cornwell later - but not able to detect her earlier?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In the Star Trek Discovery Episode [E1:E6](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Lethe_(episode)) *Leethe*, we see Admiral [Cornwell](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Katrina_Cornwell) go on a diplomatic mission to the Klingons. This results in her capture.

In the Star Trek Discovery Episode [S1:E9](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Into_the_Forest_I_Go_(episode)) *Into The Forest I Go*, they are surprised to discover Cornwell on the Klingon vessel, and beam her back with the rest of the away team.

My question is: **In Star Trek Discovery why are they able to beam out Admiral Cornwell later - but not able to detect her earlier?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked up the script for the episode (exerpt below).

They installed sensors inside the ship that would send them valuable data. These sensors would likely also detect human lifesigns, but that was not their purpose.

Everytime the cloak is engaged, the shields of the Klingon vessel are offline, but the cloak prevents the data to be sent (below: "Some sort of massive gravitational field"). Only when the ship disengages cloak, the shields are still offline for a brief moment and the data can be received by the Discovery.

> [BURNHAM] We suspect the Klingon cloak generates a massive gravitational field, one that bends light and other electromagnetic
>   waves around the ship. Essentially rendering it undetectable to our
>   sensors. But the cloak has small imperfections. So what appears like
>   background EM radiation actually contains near-imperceptible shifts
>   that correlate to the cloak's gravitational field. If we can determine
>   the exact relationship between the two, we could develop an algorithm
>   to expose any invisible ship's position.
>
> The imperfections are infinitesimal. How do we detect them?
>
> By placing sensors onboard the Klingon ship  to relay data back to Discovery.
>
> On the ship? With a boarding party? One that has to physically beam over? All right. How do we get our people there? The Klingons know
>   that Discovery is a valuable target.
>
> We use it as bait to draw their flagship away from Pahvo. They'd have to drop the cloak to engage us in battle.
>
> [BURNHAM] Shields and weapons are offline when invisible.
>   Gives us a small window to beam over after the cloak is down, - but
>   before their shields go up.
>
> [SARU] The team on the Klingon ship will install two sensors. Every time it cloaks, we gather readings.
>
> Read more:
>   https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=star-trek-discovery-2017&episode=s01e09

Once all data has been gathered, and the cloak is "effectively" rendered useless, they can detect the ship even when it's cloaked, and detect whatever is inside

> Jump protocol complete.
>
> Number One, how's that algorithm coming?
>
> Computer estimates five minutes until data analysis is complete - and
>   we can break through the cloak.
>
> We're sitting ducks. Captain, I suggest jumping to safety until the cloak has been penetrated.
>
> Why aren't they firing?
>
> They're thinking of leaving. I would.
>
> We're not going anywhere until we have Burnham and
>   Tyler back.
>
> [GRUNTING AND SHOUTING] - [YELLS, GRUNTING] - [KLINGONS
>   CHANTING] Kol! Kol! Kol! [GRUNTING] Your death will secure my place as
>   absolute ruler of the Klingon Empire.
>   - [GROWLING, SHOUTING] - [KLINGONS SHOUTING] Kill her! - [SHOUTS] - [YELLS]
>
> Captain, I've got it. Algorithm is ready. We have their
>   cloaking signature. 
>   Transferring to transporter room control.
>
> Bring them home, Number One. Locking on.
>
> Discovery to Tyler. Ready to transport.
>
> Tyler to Discovery. I have two to transport. Burnham's on the bridge.
>
> Read more:
>   https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=star-trek-discovery-2017&episode=s01e09